# Should I created the user for each tablespace in oracle DB?

Tags: oracle

Currently I am trying to connect my spring project to the oracle DB.
I used Oracle DB only once . At that time I created the sampleuser and made tables in a tablespace named sample.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE sample
DATAFILE 'C:\APP\jieun\ORADATA\XE\SAMPLE01.DBF' SIZE 11M AUTOEXTEND ON;DATA\XE\SAMPLE01.DBF' SIZE 11M AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

and then I created the user named sampleuser

```
CREATE USER sampleuser
IDENTIFIED BY password
DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
QUOTA unlimited ON users
QUOTA unlimited ON sample
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```

this sampleuser have now all the rights to create tables etc (if i understood right..)

```
 GRANT create session,     
  2        create table,
  3        create sequence,
  4        create procedure,
  5        alter session
  6  TO sampleuser ;
```

---

these are the thigns i learned so far.. but the problem is I want to connect my new project to the oracle db again.. should I repeat the above procedure again? or should I create only tablespace and reuse the sampleuser ?

I am so new to Database .. I would be so so appreciated if someone comments and or answer this question. thank you so much.

Comment: If it's the same database (e.g. you don't delete the files and recreate it with a CREATE DATABASE command, or overlay them with files from another database), then all DDL (dictionary-definition language) commands are permanent in their changes. The tablespace you created is still there, the user is still there, the grants are still there. So no, you don't repeat those steps once you have the structure defined the way you want it. You just repeat the act of connecting and making calls to the database to manipulate user data (queries, procedure executions, whatever).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, my new project is not related to the tables created in sample tablespace. In this case, should I create new tablespace? but i can still use the  user i created before(sampleuser )?

Comment: You can reuse the same tablespace, or you can create a new one, it's your choice. It sounds to me like you're doing a few small tasks, so I would just reuse the tablespace and user.

Comment: In earlier days tablespaces were used to distribute the data of large databases over several disks or even multiple machines, to optimize it and easier to maintain (backup etc). Nowadays everything is virtualized, so an advanced tablespace design is much less important. Looks like you have a small project, so stay with one tablespace for user data.

Comment: thank you so much for all of smart comments !  I am so glad you guys helped me alot thanks ✨✨